# Neo4j getting relationship name for an uknown relationship in order to render with alchemy.js

Tags: neo4j, alchemy.js

I try to fetch the relatioships in order to render a neo4j graph using alchemy.js accorfind to the [example](https://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples) I need to generate a Json that contains the nodes and links

For the nodes I manage to list all graphs nodes using the query:

```
MATCH (p) SET p.id = ID(p) return p
```

And afterwards I can manage the relationship data with:

```
MATCH (p1)-[n]->(p2) return n,ID(p1),ID(p2)
```

But how I can get the relationship name in order ot use it as caption?

I mean if I have a relationship:

```
(:POINT)-[:LINKS]->(:POINT)
```

How I can get the `LINKS` string, in other words the relatioship name.

Comment: What do you mean by `LINKS` string? Is there any property in the relationship?

Comment: The relationship name between 2 nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the path directly,

```
MATCH path = (p1)-[n]->(p2) return path
```

---

**Correction:**

you can use type(n) in cypher.

```
MATCH (p1)-[n]->(p2) return type(n)
```

Comment: I mean the type of relationship I explained it better.

Comment: you can use type(n) in cypher.